# Limitations of String Searches From MSAccess to SQl Server?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-server-2012, odbc, ms-access-2003

I am doing a large string lookup on a small table.

When I do the following query in MsAccess:

```
SELECT isBit 
FROM [SqlServerTableName] 
WHERE mycolumnName = "[String Greater Than 128 characters]"
```

I get the message:

```
The identifier that starts with [String Greater Than 128 characters] is too long. 
Maximum length is 128.
```

Followed by:

```
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string [String Greater Than 128 characters]
```

And:

```
Incorrect Syntax Near [String Greater Than 128 characters]
```

Now, is there a way around this? This table is very small and will stay very small(<1000 records) so I am not worried about string comparisons.

Comment: The character length limit for a field name in access 2003 is 64 characters.  When combined with the table name which is also 64 characters, you get a total limit of 128 characters.  it's looking for a column name because you are using opening and closing brackets. if your intention is to search the data in the field, (which has a limit of 255 characters, unless it's a memo field) remove the brackets and try again.

Comment: are your "Strings Greater Than 128 characters" all alpha numeric?  Do you have quotes in the string?

Comment: @Gene The table name is under 64 characters. The brackets were meant to show a field that is actually something else, sorry about the confusion! The string I am testing with is only text, but there will be alphanumeric strings in the future. My testing string does not have any quotations in it, but it is possible.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the string you are using to test against? are you running this query in access or SQL?

Comment: In MSAccess through ODBC. The string was simply TESTESTSETSETSETSETSET, until it was greater than 128 characters. Nothing special.

Comment: What is the SQL Server data type? Which ODBC driver are you using?

Comment: @AVG nvarchar(4000), and I am using ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server

Comment: A couple of things to try:
Use the like operator instead of =. 
Try using the native client 11 driver.
Try using an text or ntext data type. Yes, I know they are deprecated.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you link your SQL table to access instead of using the ODBC driver?

Comment: @Gene I get this error with the SQL table as a linked table. If I use a pass through it is not an issue. I am still curious to why there is a 128 character limit, hency why I haven't written up an answer yet.

Comment: I tested with one of my db's, with a string of about 170 characters and received no error.  Can you post the exact query you are using? including your test string?

Comment: Are you running this query in VBA or is it a stored query?

Comment: @Gene I have tried running it in both VBA and a stored query. The query is:

'SELECT Employee_QuickCard.isSystemCard
FROM Employee_QuickCard
WHERE employee_QuickCard.[quickCardText]="TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest"'

Comment: I'm at a loss, I've tested it wih the ODBC driver 11 for SQL Server, as well as the native client 11 and 10 drivers, and I get no error.  This leaves either some really odd type of corruption in your access file or DB, or something really odd with your table setup in SQL.  Just to test, can you convert your linked table to a local table and try again? If it works, you can limit your issues to the SQL tables themselves. maybe run a compact and compare on the DB as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`).

SQL Server is treating this as an *identifier*, and not as a string literal value.

You should change the query to be the following:

```
SELECT isBit 
FROM [SqlServerTableName] 
WHERE mycolumnName = '[String Greater Than 128 characters]'
```

Comment: When I try that I instead get an error: "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string" and Incorrect Syntax Near [String Greater Than 128 Characters]